# how to redirect a bunch of files with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, seo, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a site with a lot of url's like this

```
www.example.com/this_has_some_meaning.php
```

Now I learned that for SEO reasons it is better to use

```
www.example.com/this-has-some-meaning.php
```

Can i,  using htaccess,  redirect all the url's from the old to the new, using some kind of regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# when there is only one underscore then redirect
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,NE]

# otherwise replace each _ by - recursively
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,DPI]
```

Comment: Thanks, but why the flags are different in the 2 solutions?

Comment: Both have different purpose. `R` flag or redirect is used when only one underscore is left.

Answer (score 1):

**Use given code**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the given code developer target 5 sites separated by "|"

Comment: I don't get this? Is it sending the bots to the index page? And why?